# Alkyl shift vs Hydride shift in hydroboration-oxidation reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry

A part of the hydroboration oxidation reaction in alkenes is as follows:

[image]

but in the 4th step, why is alkyl shift happening instead of hydride shift (from Boron atom)?

Comment: Related: [Oxidation Of Trialkylborane - Doubt In Mechanism](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/29490/7951)

Comment: You get B=O -boron doesn't like to have coordination equal 2